# Random firmware error after update on my Kali system

Tags: kali-linux, error-handling, firmware

Well, isn't that just terrific. After updating my system (Kali GNU/Linux 2018.1 variation, to be specific), I got the following message on boot:

```
[   14.146398] platform regulatory.0: firmware: failed to load regulatory.db (-2)
[   14.146477] firmware_class: See https://wiki.debian.org/Firmware for information about missing firmware
```

I have no idea what to do. I checked possible conflicted packages with `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, but nothing seems to be out of place. The system itself works seemingly identically as prior to the reported error, in fact I'm typing this post on it right now. But I like to have my OS clean and in order, so I'm struggling to get rid of this error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me)

Comment: @Rui not (yet) a duplicate IMO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the very limited information you have provided it's possible you've been hit by this bug, [wireless-regdb: Missing support for kernel direct loading](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=892229).

One workaround is listed at the end of the bug report:

> Download `wireless-regdb 2017.12.23`, untar, and copy `regulatory.db` and
>   `regulatory.db.p7s` to `/lib/firmware`; full ok.

Comment: Hmmm, I'll try that. Thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Download [wireless-regdb](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/network/wireless-regdb/wireless-regdb-2017.12.23.tar.xz) 2017.12.23, untar, and **copy regulatory.db** and **regulatory.db.p7s** to **/lib/firmware**;

its working fine....100%